# Intellij debug does not kill gradle process termination

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Since I updated IntelliJ to 2018.2 my debug process starts and works fine, but when stopped app is still working in the background. Looking for PID to kill it manually everytime is kind of painful. I'm using gradle with java and scala. Anyone having same issue?

Comment: Sounds like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194325, it should be fixed in a next build, or you could use EAP.

Comment: @PetrRastegaev Thanks, for info.